# Park Tool TS-2 Truing Stand Upright Adjustment Knob

Tags: wheel-building, wheel-truing

I just bought a used TS-2 truing stand that was in storage for years. Used one time, according to the previous owner. I cannot get the Upright Adjustment Knob to move the uprights in or out. The black plastic handle has a lock nut to lock it onto the shaft but when the handle is locked in place I can't move it clockwise at all and when I try to move it counter-clockwise it loosens the handle from the locknut and the handle unscrews. Any tips on how to work this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the grease has frozen from disuse. I’d shoot some penetrating oil into the main nut/bolt junction and leave it overnight or a few days to see if it’ll loosen up.

Comment: Frozen grease doesn't seem to be the problem. All kinds of penetrating oil has made no difference. The threaded shaft does not appear to be rusty. It will not budge. Almost as if it is locked somehow.

Answer (score 1):

RoboKaren was probably right about frozen grease. I decided to install a rebuild kit that is made for this stand. Started taking it apart and got to the step that says to turn shaft to remove it. It still wouldn't turn so I put a long wrench on it and it turned. So perhaps I was being too gentle with it before. At any rate, I'm going to finish the upgrade even though the original parts are probably fine, as this stand was hardly used. Park claims the upgrade will be better anyway. Thank you RoboKaren.

Comment: Lack of use and lack of grease along may have caused the shaft to gall or cold weld itself. When you put the shaft back again, be sure to use lots of grease.